# how change telegram source from arm to x86 in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, telegram

i imported [telegram source](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)  in Android Studio.

This just run in arm cpu !
i want run in x86 emulator .

please help me .  best regards .

Comment: Android Studio, bottom left, click Build Variants, in the new window select `x86Debug` or `fatDebug` build variant, run the app. *These steps are specific to this project only!*

Comment: what difference beetwen x86 and fatDebug ? and wich version worked in arm and x86 ?

Comment: fat contains all native code, x86 contains only x86 native code (won't run on arm). Take a look at build variants here: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/build.gradle